# Jquery on click code affects every single element with a certain class instead of just the one that's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery on click code affects every single element with a certain class instead of just the one that's clicked. For example, when I click upvote on 1 image, the upvote button of all images gets grayed out, how am I supposed to make it affect only the button that I'm clicking. Here's my code:

```
if (action.val() == 'upvote') {
            if (!$('.arrowUp').hasClass('arrowUpDisabled')) {
                $('.arrowUp').addClass('arrowUpDisabled');
                if ($('.arrowDown').hasClass('arrowDownDisabled')) {$('.arrowDown').removeClass('arrowDownDisabled');}
                $.post('../includes/voting.inc.php', {id: id.val(), userId: userId.val(), action: action.val()}, function(data){
                    ratingNumber.html((data));
                }, 'json');     
            }
        } else if (action.val() == 'downvote') {
            if (!$('.arrowDown').hasClass('arrowDownDisabled')) {
                $('.arrowDown').addClass('arrowDownDisabled');
                if ($('.arrowUp').hasClass('arrowUpDisabled')) {$('.arrowUp').removeClass('arrowUpDisabled');}  
                $.post('../includes/voting.inc.php', {id: id.val(), userId: userId.val(), action: action.val()}, function(data){
                    ratingNumber.html((data));
                }, 'json');     
            }
        };
```

Comment: You can look at using $(this) . Where $(this) is the button you clicked.

Comment: To properly answer we should see more of your code. But you can already see that you're using `$('.arrowUp')` which means *Every .arrowUp* - so clearly you need to use `$(this)` at some point.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how would $(this) be used? As in a code.
Roko C, do you mean more of my html and css or javascript?

Comment: The logic involved with the binding and handling of the click events

Comment: @GeorgeAndreev yes. Try to create a [mcve].